# Unable to throw JSONexception while parsing JSON

Tags: android

I am trying to get some data from a url in my android app. I am using volley library for Get/Post request. Following is my code to get url content:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(  Request.Method.GET, R.string.login, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e("ex","Exception Caught! "+e);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

But I am getting following error in JSONException:

> Exception org.json.JSONexception is never thrown in corresponding try block

Answer (score 3):

`org.json.JSONexception` is thrown only on JSON operation. Your `try` block has no JSON operation so this error would never be thrown.

Either Change `org.json.JSONexception` to `java.lang.Exception` or remove the `try-catch` block altogether.

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("ex","Exception Caught! "+e);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was doing that. Saw my formatting after posting it.  :D

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the `JsonObjectRequest`, there is no need for the try-catch that you would typically see in a `StringRequest` where you manually would convert the String into a JSONObject.

If there are JSON-parsing errors in the `JsonObjectRequest`, then you handle that in the `onErrorResponse`